# Will There Ever Be a Read/Write Desktop Client?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api

There are a number of questions asking "Is there a desktop client?", but the answers given all say that the existing API is read-only, with no more information.

I have come to the conclusion that SO is against a public read/write API. Is that true, and if so, why?

Is there any move towards a future read/write API / desktop client?

Comment: IIRC, write access was postponed to V3 more for technical reasons. The team wanted to take more time to do things perfectly right in light of the huge threats that a write API carries, like spam, abuse, etc... so I guess the answer is that eventually, there will probably be a write API, and following that, there will probably be desktop clients that use the functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that Stack Exchange is against a public write API per se, it's just that the requirements are particularly awkward.

To be able to write which includes:

- post questions
- post answers
- vote
- vote to close
- vote do delete
- post comments

means that you have to be pretty sure that the post comes from who it claims to come from. You want to prevent the unscrupulous spamming and/or casting fraudulent votes.

With the web sites Stack Exchange are in control of the authentication process. Making sure that 3rd party developers can use the same authentication process is where (I imagine) the issues arise.

Comment: Why CW on this Chris?

Comment: @TimPost - I don't want any more meta rep and I'm not finding anything I consider worthy of a bounty.

Comment: Solution: Don't use CW and bounty me all of your extra rep

Comment: @BenBrocka - you're missing the vital point about the post being **worthy** of the bounty :)

Comment: That Clippycorn question was worthy of a *thousand* bounties